# How to insert an image from an url inside a marker with InfoWindow in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, infowindow

I have already the url image in a variable called photo and the url of the page in a variable called url, I would like to call them in my HTML

Im trying to do something like this:

```
ContentString= '<img src= "photo" alt="url" />'

marker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ContentString
```

But get no results, what is the correct form to do it? I have read about the google maps API and they create their structure for their mark-HTML is something like this..

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
  '</div>'+
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
  '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
  'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
  'Northern Territory, central Australia.'+
  'Heritage Site.</p>'+
  '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
  'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
  '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>';
```

if I try to follow this structure and add the < img > i get an empty photo.. Thank you !!

Comment: There is no problem with the variables url, photo or coordinates they are correctly parsed to the markers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate (add) elements of your string together with the `+` sign between (single, in your case) quotation marks. Like so;

```
ContentString = '<img src="' + photo + '" alt="' + url + '" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentString= '<img src= "photo" alt="url" />'
```

Needs to be

```
ContentString= '<img src= "'+photo+'" alt="'+url+'" />'
```